More verbose output of native module build phase during yarn install
My yarn install --frozen-lockfile --verbose is getting hung at what seems to be the native module/gyp build phase and I can't figure out why.
I've tried export npm_config_loglevel=verbose before running yarn install and have not gotten any more output.  Here is where it hangs (for 8+ hours):
gyp verb download contents checksum {"node-v20.16.0-headers.tar.gz":"6cc5690a67b9b1e1fa8cedaeca41f1bdb5e1af1f7948761c798d33d99f789a5c"}
gyp verb validating download checksum for node-v20.16.0-headers.tar.gz (6cc5690a67b9b1e1fa8cedaeca41f1bdb5e1af1f7948761c798d33d99f789a5c == 6cc5690a67b9b1e1fa8cedaeca41f1bdb5e1af1f7948761c798d33d99f789a5c)
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 20.16.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? Yes
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-f',
gyp info spawn args 'make',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args 'build',
gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp verb build type Release
gyp verb architecture arm64
gyp verb node dev dir /root/.cache/node-gyp/20.16.0
gyp verb python /usr/bin/python3
gyp verb `which` succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make
gyp verb bin symlinks created symlink to "/usr/bin/python3" in "/app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/node_gyp_bins" and added to PATH
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build'
  touch Release/obj.target/DTraceProviderStub.stamp
make: Leaving directory '/app/server/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build'
gyp info ok

This is running inside a docker container.  First the host info:

Docker image: node:20.16.0-bullseye-slim
Docker version 26.1.2, build 211e74b
Host: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (running on AWS Graviton)

Env info from inside the container:
# arch
aarch64

# yarn --version
1.22.22

# node --version
v20.16.0

I've narrowed it down to puppeteer@22.0.0. If not in package.json it will not hang.  Additionally, it does not hang locally (macOS) with puppeteer@22.0.0.  Only hangs in my CI env (info above).
For some unknown reason, I have a git commit that worked a few days ago in CI, that no longer does (it contains puppeteer@22.0.0).
I have confirmed PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROME_DOWNLOAD=true is set before the yarn install.
How can I get more output so I can determine why it is hanging?

Run into the same issue with 21.x.x when installing the npm package highcharts-export-server. Installs fine locally but when building a docker image & in CI it hangs. Unfortunately don't know how to get more information from that section of yarn to identify what's going on but haven found this works as a workaround:
RUN if timeout 35 yarn install; then echo $?; else yarn install; fi.
Our highcharts instance works with this, not sure if it's completely fine or if some part of puppeteer won't work but seems to be a functional stop gap.
Also worth noting, there doesn't seem to be anything around node-gyp in our logs but the "building fresh packages" step is where the hanging is happening.
